# How to convert "A PEM encoded certificate file" to text file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Rest API returns the Perm as "A PEM encoded certificate file." How to convert it to the text file like this file below:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDDTCCAfWgAwIBAgIRAOzcoUj/60jiktDEnrghGfcwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
QjEfMB0GA1UECgwWdGVzdC1qcGhhbS51bml0eWRldi5pbzEfMB0GA1UEAwwWdGVz
dC1qcGhhbS51bml0eWRldi5pbzAeFw0xODAxMTYyMjQ0MjJaFw0yODAxMTUyMjQ0
MjJaMEIxHzAdBgNVBAoMFnRlc3QtanBoYW0udW5pdHlkZXYuaW8xHzAdBgNVBAMM
FnRlc3QtanBoYW0udW5pdHlkZXYuaW8wggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAw
ggEKAoIBAQDl+WFbLhUWsjb5fAofYvI1zijEHaF52ldGahfByOjGVyJ8UaGi//CM
L7PPqbJmSceeMIdfAie5f0GVXH+NqbersH33u6oETnRG+WO9aKMTB+bbOIDSkS33
ufIhf6wSit/GhUjujnE3xuPopttS0WpcqUCFED5k2m2mumeJkmOTjngVexrKMfvQ
Va/ubYOUNpCQnTgtNxaE93qDoylB+CFmrZ3CBDbu/LnF6YNu5NYlFGoOqAeCFacr
l4ZkTwbXo3MPH/PZlqVdFQKQtwMdqioXeo0N41zaEFtU5S+YS5VArWEQwof8B/zF
5xrhIY/n2iyM5N5ln9DDJm2YwqR43BWVAgMBAAEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEB
AMVqd9kDsg+VpjA01fgxlbQmRwzNbK736OEQpEh5iIAnEleoewSt2nY4U/eCJ5eE
XqsCEvRMxWldT0soUKQxrVkK2NmnyansRCm7kFmZ3l2IJjKR909wrBdQASKZOyeG
PvwAeAHHMX1CZnFC+71WvMfnr+Cg0kI4nYeeaTVQTsTIxEt91rsFg9+YVm99ci0J
J9NMGk6Zm+DAHN09E7I2tHBxk61E1mVd9S7627XAPSVIghcZORf7dgxoRWsux3pt
I5k/2PMrSxYRx4rPDz+J7jE7dKy5ClDj1WOmPp2D/fbojXb3YotYbEwsjBAtVfDO
HBtT4Ws0m+3FBjvhemIMLK0=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

In AngularJS, Javascript
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Guess what...You don't need to CONVERT the files!

1. Copy and paste your file (to retain your original file)
   ie: 35544arrtsfevctdtys767.crt to 35544arrtsfevctdtys767-copy.crt
2. Rename your COPIED file (35544arrtsfevctdtys767-copy.crt) to name-of-your-
   choice.TXT i.e. abc.txt  (Ignore the warning that file will not be usable if
   you change the type and click OK.)
3. You now have the TEXT version of your file...

It really is that simple!

Answer (score -2):

A PEM encoded certificate is already a base64 text file. Read http://www.gtopia.org/blog/2010/02/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates/

Comment: Doesnt answer the question sorry, need to get the text out of it like in the question

Comment: I found the answer and the linked article quite relevant, so I upvoted